# In windows 7 how to refer to a cell on another file?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Usually i do that by typing = and then move to a different workbook/file and then click another cell.

The thing is when I move to a different workbook, that different workbook doesn't seem to "know" I am creating a formula. Clicking on any cell there simply well, select the cell.

I think it's new. I used to be able to do so just fine.

How to do so then?

What am I missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if you have the two Excel files opened in two different instances of Excel. Try this:

- close all files and close Excel
- open the first file
- from within Excel, use the File > Open command to open the other file.
- now both Excel files are open in the same instance of Excel.
- select an empty cell, enter a = sign to start a formula, click the other Excel file and the formula should be created correctly.

If that does not help, please describe in detail how you open the Excel files. Also, please state your Excel version, since there are significant differences.